# Angular page navigation not redirecting after form submission

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I've built a contact form using Angular in frontend and nodeJs and nodemailer in backend where after submitting the form the page must redirect to the default page set in the app. But instead, it doesn't redirect back and stays on the contact page only although the mail is getting submitted as expected. It seems that although the data is passing as expected in the backend, for some reason in the angular nothing is getting back as data in the subscribe method. That's why the redirection code is not getting executed and after some time it turns to the error block and then navigating back to the default home page. How can I fix this???

**contact component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ToastrManager } from 'ng6-toastr-notifications';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  contactForm: FormGroup;
  public formName: string;
  public formEmail: string;
  public formPhone: number;
  public formMessage: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, private _http:HttpClient, 
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private toastr: ToastrManager) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      formName: ['', Validators.required],
      formEmail: ['', Validators.required],
      formPhone: ['', Validators.required],
      formMessage: ['']
    })}

  public contact() {
  let param =  {
    'name': this.contactForm.get('formName').value,
    'email': this.contactForm.get('formEmail').value,
    'phone': this.contactForm.get('formPhone').value,
    'message': this.contactForm.get('formMessage').value,
 }
  this._http.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/blogs' + '/send/mail', param ).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data)    //nothing is coming in data although mail is getting sent
      this.toastr.successToastr('Your contact information is saved Susseccfully!', 'Success!');
        setTimeout(() =>{
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }, 1000)
    },
    error => {                      //navigating to this error block after sometime
      console.log(error);
      console.log(error.errorMessage);
      this.toastr.errorToastr('This is not good!', 'Oops!');
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    })}}
```

**node backend:**

```
app.post('http://localhost:4000'+'/send/mail', (req, res) => {   
    let user = {
                name: req.body.name,
                email: req.body.email,
                phone: req.body.phone,
                message: req.body.message
    }
    //nodemailer setup
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'mailid',
      pass: 'passkey'
    }
  });
  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'mailid',
    to: 'mailid',
    subject: 'A contact has Arrived!',
    html: `<p>Name: ${user.name}</p>
           <p>Email: ${user.email}</p>
           <p>Phone: ${user.phone}</p>
           <p>Message: ${user.message}</p>`};

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
  });
  console.log(req.body)
});
```

**app.routing:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './client/home/home.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**client-side routing:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BlogHomeComponent } from '../blog-home/blog-home.component';
import { BlogDetailComponent } from '../blog-detail/blog-detail.component';
import { BlogByCategoryComponent } from '../blog-by-category/blog-by-category.component';
import { ContactComponent } from '../contact/contact.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'blogs', component: BlogHomeComponent},
  {path: 'blog/:blogId', component: BlogDetailComponent},
  {path: 'bycategory/:categoryId', component: BlogByCategoryComponent},
  {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent}];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ClientRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from your backend, you are not sending the response.

change your `node backend` like this :

```
app.post('/send/mail', (req, res) => {
let user = {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    message: req.body.message
}
//nodemailer setup
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'webbnetdigital@gmail.com',
        pass: 'webbnet2015'
    }
});
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'webbnetdigital@gmail.com',
    to: 'tridibc2@gmail.com, shuvankarmallick3@gmail.com',
    subject: 'A new lead has Arrived!',
    html: `<p>Name: ${user.name}</p>
       <p>Email: ${user.email}</p>
       <p>Phone: ${user.phone}</p>
       <p>Message: ${user.message}</p>`
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.send({error})
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        res.send({message: 'Email sent: ' + info.response})
    }
});
```

});